# How to make navigation drawer opens when you click the floating action button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Hello I am trying to create onClickListener for floationg action button in such a way that when I click on it,Is going to open my navigation drawer.
Thank you

Comment: What problems are you having, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use material Template to implement Navigation drawer in Android Studio
http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.in/2015/03/material-design-template.html